# How do I add intensity legend of colors after I plot using grid.raster()?

Tags: r

[image]I am doing kmeans clustering on a png image and have been plotting it using grid::grid.raster(image). But I would like to put a legend which shows the intensity in a bar(from blue to red) marked with values, essentially indicating the intensity on the image. (image is an array where the third dimension equals 3 giving the red, green and blue channels.)
I thought of using grid.legend() but couldn't figure it out. I am hoping the community can help me out. Following is the image I have been using and after I perform kmeans clustering want a legend beside it that displays intensity on a continuous scale on a color bar.
Also I tried with ggplot2 and could plot the image but still couldn't plot the legend. I am providing the ggplot code for plotting the image. I can extract the RGB channels separately using ggplot2 also, so showing that also helps.

```
colassign <- rgb(Kmeans2@centers[clusters(Kmeans2),])
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = imgVEC, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(colour = colassign) +
  labs(title = paste("k-Means Clustering of", kClusters, "Colours")) +
  xlab("x") +
  ylab("y")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find a way to use grid.raster() properly but found a way to do it by ggplot2 when plotting the RGB channels separately. Note: this only works for plotting the pannels separately, but this is what I needed. Following shows the code for green channel.

```
#RGB channels are respectively stored in columns 1,2,3.
#x-axis and y-axis values are stored in columns 4,5.
#original image is a nx5 matrix
ggplot(original_img[,c(3,4,5)], aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = segmented_img[,3])) +
  scale_color_gradient2()+ 
# scale_color_distiller(palette="RdYlBu") can be used instead of scale_color_gradient2() to get color selections of choice using palette as argument.
```